# set ACL for BackupUser

Tags: linux, acl, posix

I want to backup a whole bunch of folders from different users remotely. Therefore I created a special user that is able to log into the machine and (should) have the right to read all the files via a acl.

What I have done so far is to add these acls to the home directory

```
sudo setfacl -R -m d:u:backupuser:r-X /home
sudo setfacl -R -m u:backupuser:r-X /home
```

I thought that all new files will inherit the acl from the parent folder and the backupuser is therefore able to read all files and all new files. What really happens that some new files are not readable by the backupuser. What am I missing?